# Gorm Model structure failing to bind values when using postgres function call

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a structure called "Friend"

```
type Friend struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string,
    Address string,
```

etc

I have a postgres function that returns all friends for a zipcode.

```
var friends []types.Friend
db.Raw("select findByZip(?)", zipCode).Scan(&friends)
```

The array of friends contains the correct number of records returned from the query findByZip(?)

When I iterate over the array the values for Friend are not present.

```
for _, friend := range friends {
        fmt.Println(friend.Name)
        fmt.Println(friend.Address)
        fmt.Println("--------------------")
    }
```

I am unable to get the values from the stored proc call to bind to the correct fields in the structure.

Open to any suggestions

Comment: If I'm reading https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html right, Scan may not be able to scan the raw result directly into a list of models. The second example on the page uses db.Raw().Rows() and then scans one row at a time into a model.

Comment: @RobertNubel. I do have an implementation working with db.Raw().Rows().  for rows.Next() { var meet types.Friend db.ScanRows(rows, &friend). This code is something I wish to avoid.  TO have to iterate over the result set to create the struct defeats the purpose of ORM.  I am grateful for your feedback.  There must be a way around this.

Comment: Looping is very common in idiomatic Go, so I wouldn't consider it as a blocker in my own code. But in this case, it's the use of db.Raw() that's forcing you down an awkward path -- you might be able to get a little cleaner syntax through the normal query interface. The postgres function dependency makes that tricky, but perhaps something like `db.Find(&friends).Where("id IN (SELECT id FROM findByZip(?))", zipCode)`. Maybe even `db.Select("findByZip(?)", zipCode).Find(&friends)`.

Comment: @RobertNubel again thank you for your feedback.  I am struggling to embrace that GORM fails to bind and that I am required to implement additional logic to read in each row and manually create a structure.  I am in gratitude of your feedback.  I am still new to Golang.